# PHP - user membership list using mysql two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a membership list to show from two tables.

I want to join the two tables on there id's

database table - user

[image: database table - user],

database table - user_data

[image: database table - user_data]

Currently I'm getting only the `id=1` from user table with user data as well.

I know I want to loop it to see all the records from the user table but I don't how too. I am new to coding.

```
{

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_active='Yes' AND user_id!=0 ") or die(mysql_error()); 
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

     foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $output[$key] = $value;
     } 

    $user_id=$output['user_id'];

        // now we get the user information and add it to the $output array.
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT data_type,data_value FROM user_data WHERE data_user_id=$user_id ") or die(mysql_error()); 
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $output['user_data'][$row['data_type']] = $row['data_value'];

     }

    print_r($output);
}
```

Comment: First please stop using depreciated functions

Comment: what is the error? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Put print_r($row) inside the while loop, then you will know what to do

Answer (score 0):

***Only one request is needed*** in this context you have to rewrite your SQL call.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_active, ud.data_type, ud.data_value FROM user u 
JOIN user_data ud 
ON u.user_id = ud.user_id 
WHERE u.user_active='Yes' AND data_user_id!=0
```

I **JOIN** the 2 tables with **ALIAS** tables u and ud (user,user_data) with the same id in your context user_id and data_user_id :

```
// now we get the user information and add it to the $output array.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT u.user_id, u.user_active, ud.data_type, ud.data_value FROM user u 
                       JOIN user_data ud 
                       ON u.user_id = ud.user_id 
                       WHERE u.user_active='Yes' AND data_user_id!=0") or die(mysql_error()); 
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $output['user_data'][$row['data_type']] = $row['data_value'];

     }

print_r($output);
```

Regards.